# Why can I use numpy functions on Pandas DataFrames?

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I found found out accidentally that NumPy functions can be directly applied to Pandas DataFrames. For example:

```
np.log(my_pandas_df)
```

works. This is not something that I expected to work since NumPy knows nothing about Pandas. What is happening behind the scenes?

Comment: pandas is built in numpy arrays, so it working, mainly if numeric data

Comment: pandas uses numpy check with `pd.np.log` for example

Comment: Numpy doesn't have to know about Pandas. Because of duck typing, Pandas just has to implement an interface that Numpy recognizes, in most cases with an implied `map` behaviour of the numpy function over the dataframe.

Comment: `my_pandas_df.to_numpy()` produces a numpy array.    `np.array(my_pandas_df)` effectively does the same.  Think of `np.log` doing `np.log(np.array(df))`.  This only works if the resulting array is numeric.  If the `df` contains strings (object dtype) it will fail.

Comment: @hpaulj `np.log(df)` is not the same as `np.log(np.array(df))`.  The former returns a dataframe and the latter returns a numpy array.  Is it better to say "think of `np.log(df)` as `df.apply(np.log)`"?

Answer (score 0):

Numpy is the foundation of library likes Pandas, Matplotlib, etc. You should use panda functions better because they are more friendly that numpy.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).